# How to reload the page with new data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I load a webpage for the first time I call this function to load up the data.

```
 function campusInfo(id) {
```

(calls a third party api and gets data to display on page for the id passed in....)

I have a hyperlink on the same page that when clicked it calls this same function and passes in a new id. I would like when this hyperlink is clicked the page should load with new data that is unique to this id, instead it loads up the data but is appending it to the data that already exists on the page from the initial load. 
I need to somehow clean out the old data from the page when this hyperlink is clicked. Here is my code for the hyperlink: notice i'm using a div and not an actual hyperlink and calling the campusInfo() function.

```
 $(r.campuses).each(function (index, item) {
            if (item.campusID != id) { // checks if the current other schools id is not equal to current page main school id 
                    var HTMLcontentSchool = '<div class="ml-32 mt-16 mb"><div class="other-school" onclick="campusInfo(' 
                    + item.campusID + ')"><label class="other-schools-list">' + item.campusName + '</label></div><br /></div>';
                    $('.group').append(HTMLcontentSchool);                     
                }
```

Comment: give html code also, your hyperlink,dynamic data appending div etc.. are need to answer this...

Answer (score 0):

If the element `$('.group')` has nothing other than the data inside you could use the [`$.empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function to clear all of its contents. Like so:

```
 $(r.campuses).each(function (index, item) {
    if (item.campusID != id) { // checks if the current other schools id is not equal to current page main school id 
            var HTMLcontentSchool = '<div class="ml-32 mt-16 mb"><div class="other-school" onclick="campusInfo(' 
            + item.campusID + ')"><label class="other-schools-list">' + item.campusName + '</label></div><br /></div>';
            $('.group').empty();  // <----------------------Empties contents
            $('.group').append(HTMLcontentSchool);                     
        }
```

Otherwise if there are other child elements that need to remain, you'll have to keep a reference of the previously added node for removal later. Like so:

```
var addedData = null;
$(r.campuses).each(function (index, item) {
    if (item.campusID != id) { // checks if the current other schools id is not equal to current page main school id 
            var HTMLcontentSchool = '<div class="ml-32 mt-16 mb"><div class="other-school" onclick="campusInfo(' 
            + item.campusID + ')"><label class="other-schools-list">' + item.campusName + '</label></div><br /></div>';
            if (!!addedData) { addedData.remove() } // check is exists, if so, remove.
            addedData = $(HTMLcontentSchool) // wrap as a jQuery object
            $('.group').append(HTMLcontentSchool);                     
        }
```

Comment: this is where i am looping through the campuses to display a list of hyperlinks of campuses. When I do .empty() it only showed me 1 campus instead of 3.

Comment: Ah my bad. The code should be where you're appending the 'new data'. Still the concept remains the same.

Comment: for some reason when I click on one of the hyperlinks addedData is null. Although I saw it being set on the initial load when I stepped through the code. Its not preserving its value or maybe it's getting reset.

Comment: Maybe the `var addedData = null` is within the scope of the function that's triggered whenever you click the hyperlinks. You could try moving it up.